# Forcing login autofill on a site where autofill is broken or disabled

Tags: javascript, forms, autofill

I daily visit a couple of sites where the devs for whatever reason have respectively mangled and disabled the login submittal, so neither autofill nor OnePassword can fill the login and password fields.

How can I avoid typing my name and login on every single visit?

I'm open to any approach to get autofill working - greasemonkey, or spoofing form submittal from another page.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is with a bookmarklet:

```
javascript:document.forms[0].username.value = 'username'; document.forms[0].password.value = 'password'; document.forms[0].submit();
```

Make a bookmark of a random page, then edit it and put that text instead of "http://...".  You may need to play with it if it's not the first form on the page, or if their fields are named differently.  (View source, and/or right-click and select "inspect element" to find the name)

When you get to the page, click the bookmarklet to login.